# bad_weak_ptr with boost smart pointer

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio, boost-beast

I develop a desktop chat with boost asio and beast (for browser support).

I use this architecture :
[image]

But, when building, I have an issue : `bad_weak_ptr`, I don't know what is wrong :s
Here a link to the source
https://onlinegdb.com/BkFhDGHe4

**Update1** :
I remove run() function into constructor and move it into handle_accept function, tcp_server class. like this:

`void tcp_server::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code ec, websocket_session_ptr new_websocket)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
     // Happens when the timer closes the socket
    if(ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
        return;
    new_websocket->run(); //Here
    chatwebsocketsessionpointer session = chat_websocket_session::create(room, new_websocket);
    room->join(session);
    wait_for_connection();
    }
}`

I can see the chat_webocket_session is deleted, but still have issue with `bad_weak_ptr`

**Update 2 :**
I found where is the issue.
If I never call do_read() function, there is no error, and I can connect to server with ws
If I call it into wait_for_data from chat_websoket_session class, I have issue.
So I must found how call do_read()

**Update 3 :**
If I do 
`websocket_session_ptr new_websocket(new websocket_session(std::move(socket)));
    acceptor.async_accept(
            socket,
            boost::bind(
                &tcp_server::websocket_accept,
                this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        new_websocket
        ));`

making ref to : [boost beast websocket example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp), I accept first the socket, and after I accept the websocket with `m_ws.async_accept()` but I have now `Bad file descriptor` which means the socket is not open.

P.S: I update the ide URL (GDB online debugger)

Comment: Instead of pretty diagrams - which tell us nothing about the code, reduce your code to the minimum code that shows the problem, and include it in the question. Your problem was about the code, not about OOP design

Comment: You are getting `accept: operation cancelled` because you are calling `async_accept` with the socket which was moved one line above. `std::move(socket)` into `new_websocket`. After moving `socket` is useless, and you should not pass it to async_accept.

Comment: If I move run() into wait_for_data() or constructor from chat_websocket_session class, I have the same issue

Comment: if I remove std::move(socket) from websocket_session constructor and `websocket_session_ptr new_websocket(new websocket_session(socket));` I have `use of deleted function`

Answer (score 3):

You're using the shared pointer to this from inside the constructor:

```
websocket_session::websocket_session(tcp::socket socket)
        : m_ws(std::move(socket))
        , strand(socket.get_executor())
{
    run();
}
```

Inside `run()` you do

```
void websocket_session::run() {
    // Accept the websocket handshake
    std::cout << "Accepted connection" << std::endl;
    m_ws.async_accept(boost::asio::bind_executor(
        strand, std::bind(&websocket_session::on_accept, , std::placeholders::_1)));
}
```

That uses `shared_from_this()` which will try to lock the unitialized `weak_ptr` from `enable_shared_from_this`. As you can see in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) that throws the `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception (ad. 11)

The documentation to [`shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) explicitly warns against this:

> It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr (***in particular, shared_from_this cannot be called in a constructor***).

Comment: I delete run() function from constructor, and call this function into wait_for_data() function (chat_websocket_session class ). I have still issue.

Comment: The whole point of making `run` a separately invoked member function is precisely because you cannot call `shared_from_this` in a constructor :)

Comment: Audit all cases where you construct a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` including all calls to `shared_from_this`. Make sure there's no way they can be called before the object is fully constructed or after its destructor has been invoked. You can also just use a debugger that can break on a throw and see what code is doing it.

Comment: I change shared_from_this() to this into websocket_session() bind function and it resolved the issue, but now I have `accept : operation canceled `

Comment: @Vana that's fortunate because it shielded you from undefined behaviour. `operation aborted` is the natural consequence of the Io object instance being destructed